# Unable to view aura component in lightning experience.Do I need to enable any setting to view components in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

```
<p>Message of the day: {!v.message}</p>

<div>
    <lightning:button label="You look nice today."
        onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>

    <lightning:button label="Today is going to be a great day!"
        onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
</div>
```

Below is the format I am able to see on clicking preview.
[image]

[image]
 Above format is what I want to see(Trailhead Module image)

Comment: How are you trying to view the component? What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to view this component by adding to aura application and using preview option(This is a trailhead module learning example which I am trying to view):
<aura:application >
    <c:HelloMessageInteractive/>
</aura:application>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extends="force:slds" include this at the top in your application like

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
```